# Remove all table widths from editor content

Tags: editor, regex, wp-kses

When I paste a table into the WordPress editor, I always get widths like `<td width="232">`.

I want to remove all widths when tables are added to the editor.

If it was regex, I would write something like: `width="([0-9]+)"`.

How do I go about accomplishing this?

Comment: Working to get your question reopened since this is a relevant WordPress question.

Answer (score 1):

I would approach this by modifying the attributes allowed in the table, tr, and td markup from `wp_kses`. [`wp_kses`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_kses) is a function that runs on the content to filter out unwanted tags and attributes. It stands for KSES Strips Evil Scripts, but it does much more than that.

It's a large and sometimes convoluted function, but it's very useful if you want to extend or modify what it filters out.

Keep in mind, this only applies to users without the `unfiltered_html` capability.

The `wp_kses_allowed_html` filter allows you to modify the allowed tags and attributes. The array structure is `$allowedtags['tag_name']['attribute']`, so you would look for `$allowedtags['table']['width']`, for example.

```
function my_modify_tags( $tags, $context ) {
    if ( 'post' !== $context ) {
        return $tags;
    }
    if ( isset( $tags['table']['width'] ) ) {
        unset( $tags['table']['width'] );
    }
    if ( isset( $tags['td']['width'] ) ) {
        unset( $tags['td']['width'] );
    }
    if ( isset( $tags['th']['width'] ) ) {
        unset( $tags['th']['width'] );
    }
    return $tags;
}
add_filter( 'wp_kses_allowed_html', 'my_modify_tags', 1, 2 );
```

The `$context` here allows for this to apply to specific instances where you want to modify the tags. By targeting `post`, you can have this filtered list of allowed tags only apply to the post content.